# Example of a non-convex set for which A + A = 2A

Tags: functional-analysis

Give an example of a non-convex subset $A$ of a (real / complex) vector space $V$ for which 
$$A + A  = 2A$$
Here the sum / multiplication with a scalar of a subset is defined in the obvious way.

I am new to functional analysis, and most of my intuition for vector spaces comes from finite-dimensional ones. All non-convex sets that I can think of in finite-dimensional vector spaces do not to satisfy this equality, so I figure an example must come from an infinite dimensional space.

Any examples to consider will be helpful, even if just examples of non-convex sets in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: take $A=\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $A = \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. (If a subset, $A$, of a vector space is a **2-divisible subgroup**, then $A + A = 2 A$ will hold, but a subgroup can only be convex if it is a **subspace**.)

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$ or $2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: $0\in\mathbb Z$ and $0+n=n$ so...